# How does the Camera app decide to create a new folder when saving pictures/videos?

Tags: iphone, ios, camera

I wonder how does the camera app decides to create a new folder when saving pictures/videos.

I see there is at least one new folder per month, assuming at least 1 pictures/video was taken in this month. But within the month, the camera app may decides to create multiple folder. Example:

[image]

Some of these folders contain very few files:

[image]

[image]

And some folders contain multiple days:

[image]

So I don't see a clear pattern.
How does the Camera app decide to create a new folder when saving pictures/videos?

Comment: What is the practical problem you are trying to solve here?

Comment: @nohillside trying to prioritize which folders to backup

Comment: You will get better answers if you ask about how to accomplish this (because the rules to create new folders may or may not be relevant for this).

Comment: Windows' Phtos app will know [after the first sync] which photos have not been transferred. There's no need to dig around in the folder hierarchy any more. MS Photos handles it rather like Mac's Photos app does these days. It can even handle heif/heic files [with a plugin it gets from the Win Store as it needs it.]